# The method 'installAppCheckProviderFactory' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAppCheck'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

i am trying to use firebase new feature which is App check for flutter app in android emulator.
i am trying to activate the debug provider for android by following this instructions [app check](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/usage/#add-a-debug-token-to-firebase-project-settings) .

for line "firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());" , i got error message that says The method 'installAppCheckProviderFactory' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAppCheck'

does anyone know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem myself.
It's not stated on this page but the imports you need are:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.debug.DebugAppCheckProviderFactory;
```

Comment: works for me, must be copied in MainActivity.java